# How do I dump Python's logging configuration?

Tags: python, python-logging

How do I dump the current configuration of the Python `logging` module? For example, if I use a module that configures logging for me, how can I see what it has done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be a documented way to do so, but we can get hints by looking at how the `logging` module is implemented.

All `Logger`s belong to a tree, with the root `Logger` instance at `logging.root`. The `Logger` instances do not track their own children but instead have a shared `Manager` that can be used to get a list of all loggers:

```
>>> print(logging.root.manager.loggerDict)
{
  'rosgraph': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0xffffa2851710>,
  'rosgraph.network': <logging.Logger object at 0xffffa28517d0>,
  'rosout': <rosgraph.roslogging.RospyLogger object at 0xffffa2526290>,
  'rospy': <rosgraph.roslogging.RospyLogger object at 0xffffa2594250>,
  ...
}
```

Each `Logger` instance has `handlers` and `filters` attributes which can help understand the behavior of the logger.